# IIS virtualpath and UriBuilder

Tags: c#, iis, uribuilder

I'm having multiple applications hosted under one site in `IIS`. Each application have unique `VirtualPath`, so i have something like this:

1. localhost/Site1
2. localhost/Site2
3. ...
4. locahost/SiteN

What I'm trying to do - to build valid URL using out of the box helpers, like `UriBuilder`. Problem is that using default constructor like

```
var builder = new System.UriBuilder("https://mysite/Site1");
```

will split my address into

1. Host: mysite
2. Path: Site1

Is there any "right approach" or best practices for generating addresses for sites hosted like this?

Comment: Are you trying to access the virtual paths of the other sites in one site?

Comment: I'm trying to get right url, when I'm using builder.ToString(). Problems begin when I'm assigning Path to string builder - the "site1" part dissapears

Comment: Have you tried the `Uri` class? With it you can combine any base url and right url. e.g. `var uri1 = new Uri("https://mysite/site1", "mypath.html");`